# Como obtener registro de id y mostrar en vista?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un listado de ofertas laborales, como tambien un listado de las postulaciones (el programa es un portal de empleo). Necesito generar que por mediante de un link de las ofertas laborales, me muestre los usuarios que han postulado a dicha oferta laboral, pero no entiendo como hacerlo. Dejaré imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que el usuario haga click en "Postulación" para ver a los usuarios postulados de esa oferta.

Controlador OfertaPostulante:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.OfPostUsr_ID = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindByName(User.Identity.Name).Email;
        ViewBag.OfPostOf_ID = new SelectList(db.OfertaLaboral, "Of_ID", "Of_Titulo");
        var asd = (from oferta in db.OfertaLaboral select oferta).ToList();
        ViewBag.asd1 = asd;
        IEnumerable <OfertaLaboral> otrointento = from oferta in db.OfertaLaboral select oferta;
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "OfPost_ID,OfPostOf_ID,OfPostUsr_ID,OfPostFecha")] OfertaPostulante ofertaPostulante)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.OfertaPostulante.Add(ofertaPostulante);
            var Datetimenow = DateTime.Now;
            ofertaPostulante.OfPostFecha = new DateTime(Datetimenow.Year, Datetimenow.Month, Datetimenow.Day, Datetimenow.Hour, Datetimenow.Minute, 0);
            ofertaPostulante.OfPostUsr_ID = HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId();
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Success");
        }

        ViewBag.OfPostUsr_ID = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "Email", ofertaPostulante.OfPostUsr_ID);
        ViewBag.OfPostOf_ID = new SelectList(db.OfertaLaboral, "Of_ID", "Of_Titulo", ofertaPostulante.OfPostOf_ID);
        return View(ofertaPostulante);
    }
```

Modelo oferta laboral:

```
 namespace ProyectoBase4.Models
 {
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class OfertaLaboral
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public OfertaLaboral()
    {
        this.OfertaPostulante = new HashSet<OfertaPostulante>();
    }

    public int Of_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> OfEmp_ID { get; set; }
    public string Of_Titulo { get; set; }
    public string Of_Puesto { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Of_Area { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Of_Subarea { get; set; }
    public string Of_Descrp { get; set; }
    public string Of_Lugar { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Of_Vacante { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Of_FechaIn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Of_FechaFin { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Of_Salario { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Of_Jornada { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Of_Mov { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Of_Edu { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Of_TContrato { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Of_Estado { get; set; }

    public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
    public virtual Educacion Educacion { get; set; }
    public virtual Estado Estado { get; set; }
    public virtual Jornada_Compl Jornada_Compl { get; set; }
    public virtual Movilidad Movilidad { get; set; }
    public virtual Subarea Subarea { get; set; }
    public virtual TipoContrato TipoContrato { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<OfertaPostulante> OfertaPostulante { get; set; }
}
}
```

Modelo Oferta Postulante:

```
   namespace ProyectoBase4.Models
 {
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class OfertaPostulante
{
    public int OfPost_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> OfPostOf_ID { get; set; }
    public string OfPostUsr_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> OfPostFecha { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUsers AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual OfertaLaboral OfertaLaboral { get; set; }
}
}
```

Nota*: el botón "Ver postulaciones" me muestra las postulaciones de usuario, pero lo que necesito es que por cada ID de oferta laboral, haya un link que me muestre todos los usuarios postulados, dejaré imagen:

[image: Ver postulaciones]

Gracias!

Comment: Por lo que noté en tu modelo, una oferta laboral tiene asignado un listado de ofertaPostulante... cuando haces un toList() a la tabla OfertaLaboral que es lo que trae? Porque deberías poder acceder al listado de los postulantes si no entendí mal tu modelo

Comment: Lo que trae son todas las ofertas creadas, como se muestra en la primera imagen. Cuando hago un toList() a OfertaPostulante, se muestra el correo del usuario y el nombre del titulo, ahí no hay problema. Lo que necesito es que, mediante el link "postulación" que iría en todas las ofertas (al igual que los métodos "editar" y "detalles"), al hacer click, me muestre los usuarios que hayan postulado a dicha oferta, que no entiendo cómo hacerlo. En la segunda imagen me muestra las postulaciones de los usuarios. pero muestra 1 en 1. Gracias por responder :)

Comment: Entiendo eso, pero en teoría si pones un punto de interrupción donde llamas al toList() debería traer una propiedad de tipo OfertaPostulante que sería el listado de todos los postulantes. Supongo que estas utilizando EntityFramework para trabajar =/

Comment: Así es... soy principiante en esto, no comprendo mucho :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega un link nuevo igual al de detalles. Pero esta vez que valla a otra acción de tu controlador, en este caso puede ser PostulantesDeOferta.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("PostulantesDeOferta", "Oferta", new {id = item.Id}) ">Postulación</a>
```

Este link ejecuta la acción PostulantesDeOferta del controlador Oferta, pasando el Id de esa oferta como parámetro, el mismo principio del Edit y el Details.

y en tu controlador agregar la acción:

```
public ActionResult PostulantesDeOferta(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var of_postulantes = db.OfertaPostulantes.Include(o => o.AspNetUsers).Where(o => o.OfPostOf_ID == id);                

            return View(of_postulantes);
        }
```

y en tu vista tu modelo seria un

```
IEnumerable<OfertaPostulante>
```

podiras acceder a `@item.AspNetUser.UserName`

Nota, en mi opinion AspNetUsers es el nombre de la tabla que crea Identity, por lo tienes algunas inconsistencias en el modelo, yo trabajarías con ApplicationUser y no con AspNetUsers.

Comment: Esto me ha funcionado, con un foreach de OfertasPostulantes, me arroja el ID, pero como lo puedo hacer, para que me muestre el "Email" por ejemplo?, ya que me toma los campos de "OfertaPostulante" en este caso: OfPostUsr_ID, pero necesito que me muestre otro campo, para generar más información.

Comment: Al final pude hacerlo, importando el modelo de usuarios. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, funciona !